# How to selective install package in one pypi project which has multiple packages?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, setup.py, pypi

I have next folder structure:

```
.
├── demo
│   └── __init__.py
├── demo2
│   └── __init__.py
└── setup.py
```

**demo/__init__.py:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-
def test():
    print("demo1!")
if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

**demo2/__init__.py:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-
def test():
    print("demo2!")
if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

**setup.py:**

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name="demo20210216",
    version="0.1.0",
    packages=find_packages(),
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'demo = demo:test',
            'demo2 = demo2:test',
        ]
    }
)
```

I use next to upload to [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/demo20210216/0.1.0/):

```
# python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
# twine upload dist/*
```

Then I could use `pip install demo20210216` to install the package, and could verify I have two package `demo` & `demo2` installed, meanwhile script `demo` & `demo2` installed in Scripts folder.

**Problem:**

Everything is fine, just for `demo2`, most of my audience do not need it.
So, I want to find a way: default just install `demo1`, but if user needed, he/she could use an additional way to install `demo2`, is there a way to realize it in pip?

(PS: I don't want to separate `demo1` and `demo2` to different pypi project)

Comment: No, there isn't. PyPI packages are atomic and not dividable into parts. Make another PyPI package `demo2` and declare it an optional dependency on `demo1`, e.g. `pip install demo1[extras]` will install `demo1` and `demo2`.

Comment: @hoefling YES, this workaround looks good, at least to audience they still looks working on one package even it not. So, thanks, if you like, you could send this as an answer then I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, didn't find any more solutions, just use the solution in comments: that is using one wrapper project depends on other projects (demo1, demo2):

**setup.py:**

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name="demowrapper",
    version="0.1.0",
    packages=find_packages(),

    extras_require={
        'demo1': ['demo1'],
        'demo2': ['demo2'],
    },
)
```

Then, at least, to user, it looks still could face to one top project `demowrapper`, and could select the component to install with `pip install demowrapper[demo1]`.